# difficulty with datatool + keyval

Tags: key-value, datatool

I want to define a command with key arguments, which stores something in a table with help of the package datatool. My attempt is :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{keycommand}
\RequirePackage{datatool}
\begin{document}
  % declare a new table
\DTLnewdb{table}
  % define the command
\newkeycommand{\myCom}[op=1]{%
\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{option}{\commandkey{op}}
}
%call 4 times the command
\myCom[op=2] 
\myCom[op=3]
\myCom[op=4]
\myCom[op=5]
% display the content of the table
\DTLdisplaydb{table}
```

I would expect "2 3 4 5", but i get "5 5 5 5".
This is actually a common problem that i encounter regularly with datatools (that somehow "only the last operation is taken into account"), which shows probably that i still don't know how to use it properly... 
What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I checked the `datatool` manual and found the following note about `\DTLnewdbentry` (page 32):

> The value isn’t expanded by default, but you can change this using the declaration: `\dtlexpandnewvalue`. This can be localised by placing it in a group, or you can switch back using: `\dtlnoexpandnewvalue`.

I simply rewrote `\myCom`:

```
\newkeycommand{\myCom}[op=1]{%
\DTLnewrow{table}
\dtlexpandnewvalue
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{option}{\commandkey{op}}%
\dtlnoexpandnewvalue
}
```

Now the output is correct:

[image: Datatool output]

Comment: great ! i think, this solves some of my other problems with datatool ! :)

Comment: @nicolasroy: glad to hear! `:)` I updated the code with `\dtlnoexpandnewvalue` right after the insertion.

Comment: yes, without `\dtlnoexpandnewvalue`, one gets some bad errors...